# sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, dllimport

i am facing this issue while trying to run my kivy ml application in PowerShell or cmd.
i have installed all kivy dependencies but still same error. also i have tried to run it in virtual environment.

```html
(kivy_venv) PS C:\Users\thiru\Downloads\exe file> python3 main.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\thiru\.kivy\logs\kivy_22-01-24_7.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.3.3
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\thiru\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.9 (main, Jan 15 2022, 01:02:02) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "c:\users\thiru\appdata\local\activestate\cache\cc3d5c70\python.exe"
2022-01-24 14:14:10.715828: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2022-01-24 14:14:10.723572: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\thiru\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 58, in core_select_lib
    mod = __import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
  File "C:\Users\thiru\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Tess did my answer help?